# adding data with template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have a design question. I'm using sort of solution to this question but I don't really like it and I am not sure if the other option I'm thinking is a good thing to do. Also other ideas are welcome.

Consider

```
struct Mminus
{    /*empty*/ };

struct Mplus
{    /*mainly data members*/ };

template <typename More> class MyClass : More
{
    // etc.
};
```

`MyClass` has a single instance, but used in different projects with almost similar functionality. The work around the extra data is heavy, so when not used should be removed during compilation.

Now `MyClass<Mplus>` do the same thing as `MyClass<Mminus>` + extra steps of initialization of the `Mplus` data and a some use of this data in the exposed functionality.

The data initialization in `Mplus` need things known to `MyClass<Mplus>` which are not nice to send as parameters to move that initialization to be part of `<Mplus>`.

The solution I use is

```
template<typename M> 
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<M, Mplus>::value>::type
InitilalizeData()
{/*etc*/}

template<typename M> 
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<M, Mminus>::value>::type
InitilalizeData()
{/*do nothing*/}
```

then call it as

```
InitilalizeData<More>();
```

I do not really like this solution because eventually similar `enable_if` template functions required in the pieces of code using this extra data;

Would it be valid solution to have something like

```
    template <> class MyClass<Mminus>
    {
        // etc.
    };

    //Any other 
    template <typename Mplus> class MyClass<Mplus>:  MyClass<Mminus>, Mplus
    {
        // etc.
    };
```

any other idea?

Comment: yep, I've fixed this now

Comment: It’s still not a valid partial specialization, because it has the same template parameter list as the primary template.

Comment: I see, actually I discovered this the hard way:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can define a common interface, perhaps including no-ops for `Mminus` (like your `InitilalizeData`), then you can just define those methods in `Mminus` and `Mplus` and any calls on/in `MyClass` will use whichever version is inherited.  If the methods need access to common `MyClass` features, it might be more natural to invert the inheritance with the CRTP:

```
template<class D> struct MyClass {
  int init() {
    common=42;
    d().InitilalizeData();
    return common;
  }
protected:
  int common;
private:
  D& d() {return static_cast<D&>(*this);}
};
struct Mminus : MyClass<Mminus> {
  void InitilalizeData() {}
};
struct Mplus : MyClass<Mplus> {
  void InitilalizeData() {++common;}
};
```

Comment: Accepting this for the detailed example. Unfortunately it didn't solve my real more complicate problem, but it definitely will be a part of the solution^)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the problem you are having could be solved with polymorphism. If for some reason that is not possible and you need this resolved at compile time. You could go for [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: can you please elaborate, an example using the CRTP

Comment: Here is the link to a couple of examples. That I think are quite well explained:
https://codeyarns.com/2015/07/09/how-to-understand-crtp/
and
http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-is-still-lazy